# wrong section order when linking flat binary

Tags: assembly, x86-16, ld, osdev, gnu-assembler

So I'm trying to link 16-bit assembly code which jumps to 64-bit rust code.
It worked before but now it for some reason doesn't work.
So Assembly code that boot sector program should run is in `_start` function, this file is flat binary after linking so it doesn't look for `_start` function but just runs first bytes of code.
I'm trying to link it with this command:
`x86_64-linux-gnu-ld --gc-sections -Ttext 0x7e00 --oformat binary -e 0x7e00 -o {some file} {assembly elf file} {rust elf file}`
Assembly first lines looks like this:

```
extern rust_start, GDT, IDT
bits 16

; arguments: string segment, string address, text color
%macro println 3

    mov ax, %1
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, %2
    mov dx, %3
    mov si, 0x7ce0
    call si

%endmacro

; here bootsector program jumps in real mode, this function doesn't return
_start:
    hlt ; temporarily
    ...
```

for some reason instead of `hlt` instruction being first (which is 0xf4 byte) it fills first 32 bytes with some junk and then `hlt` starts.

I really have no idea whats going on so I didn't try much, it just stopped working correctly.

Comment: I'd recommend doing this `x86_64-linux-gnu-ld --gc-sections -Ttext 0x7e00 -e 0x7e00 -o kernel.elf {assembly elf file} {rust elf file}` and then do `objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin`. This creates an ELF executable and then converts that ELF to a binary file. The advantage is you can now do an `objdump -Dx kernel.elf` to dump out the sections and the headers. It might give a hint as to why `hlt` isn't first.

Comment: Since you are not using a linker script, one possibility is that the rust compiler output a `.text.startup` section, and the default linker script that comes with LD/binutils placed that code before the actual `.text` section when you linked everything with GCC. The default linker script has a rule that puts `.text.startup` before `.text`. This is just a wild guess, but one possibility. I'd really recommend creating your own linker script.

Comment: `.text.startup` is just one possibility. Anyway, doing `objdump -Dx kernel.elf` may at least get you on the right path to figuring it out.